# Class Row in Bootstrap not working if connected to the database

Tags: php, mysql

So like this, I intend to make a row with bootstrap using `col-md-5`. I think will make three container lined up. But when I connect to the database, the result is not as hopeful !! I think the result can still lined up but even down to the bottom. any solutions?

This is the coding and the result when I connect to the database and I do not connect to the database - [full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTpjm.jpg)

[image: this is the coding and the result when I connect to the database and I do not connect to the database]

Comment: To ask an On Topic questions, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Also never post pictures of code, instead post the text into your question

Comment: make image inline

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are putting the `div` having the `row` class inside the loop, on every iteration the `row` class is repeated which makes the new row for each iteration. Put the div with `row` class outside of loop, like:

```
<div class="row">
...
while(...)
{

}
...
</div>
```

Comment: do you have a solution to this problem? or can you exemplify it to me?

Comment: before while (..) no need to use col-span? example 
<div class="row"> ...
<div class="col-md-5>
while(...)
{
}

Answer (score 0):

You included the div with a row class inside the loop that's why it is displayed vertically.

Inside your while statement loop only the div with col class while the row div is outside the loop

```
<div class="row">
<? Your php while loop code ?>
<div class="col-lg-3">...</div>
<? end of your while loop?>
</div> <!-- end of your div row -->
```